# Custom attributes/properties for cells in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm interested in making an Excel cell formatting macro that allows me to scroll through different options (different font/cell colors, different border types, etc.). I know that I could accomplish this by checking conditions -- if I'm changing font colors, then I can just "scroll" by using conditional logic (if color1, then change to color2; if color2, then change to color 3; etc.). I was wondering if there might be a more elegant way to accomplish this -- specifically, is there a way to store custom attributes for cells in VBA?

For example, if I set cell B3 to a certain border style (thin line for top,left,right but double line for bottom), is there a way to create and set a VBA attribute of Cell.CustomBorderStyle = 1? Otherwise, I believe I would have to build logic into my macro for the precise formatting (if top,left,right = thin and bottom = double then change to second style, etc.). I'm not sure if creating a custom class in VBA would allow me to do this, or if there's any way at all to do this.

Please let me know if my question is unclear -- thanks!

Comment: Do your notations need to persist across sessions?  If Yes then you could consider either storing the style info in a hidden sheet (keyed to the cell address for example).  However, if a user for example adds or deletes a row/column then that's going to throw off your mapping.  One other option is to store the info in a cell comment and hide the comments.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want the cell attribute to be available within this VBA session then I would use a collection or dictionary with a key of the cell address (Sheet_Row_Column) to store the attribute(s).

If you want to persist this information within an Excel workbook then it would probably be best done using custom xml.